# sqliteconnection over network shared path (Universal Windows Platform)

Tags: sqlite, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-iot-core, storagefile

Attempting to access an sqlite file over a shared folder.
 (currently it is a default shared folder of Windows IOT)

```
string path = Settings.FullPathSQLite;
            //path  value is\\192.168.18.182\C$\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\Packages\06fb6d66-31b3-4beb-893c-2e0d9fe465f1_3asabdzxmrwg6\LocalState\Project1\settings.sqlite

            var conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);
```

throws error. but file location correct.

```
"Could not open database file: \\\\192.168.18.182\\C$\\Data\\Users\\DefaultAccount\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\06fb6d66-31b3-4beb-893c-2e0d9fe465f1_3asabdzxmrwg6\\LocalState\\Portaokul\\settings.sqlite (CannotOpen)"
```

I can access files using StorageFile or StorageFolder classes.
but cant figured it out how to modify SQLite Connection Path. have you any idea?

attaching network path to a drivename may allow accessing? so eg. "Z:\settings.sqlite" file is accesible via a normal desktop application. but not avaible for UWP.

Closest scenario I found is; copy file to local>modify>and upload back to network place. [uwpc-copy-database-from-installed-location-to-local-folder](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a2b445f4-06a2-4ec5-94fb-95f84caaa348/uwpc-copy-database-from-installed-location-to-local-folder?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: Do you have all the correct permissions in your Package manifest? Accessing files over local networks needs some special permissions IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP,apps can access certain file system locations by default, please refer to [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) in MSDN. Even though you can access folders out of your app private storage area,the SQLiteApi in UWP does not support for SQLite which expects a filename. Currently it seems no way to do this other than to copy your database to your UWP app local storage area.

Comment: Two years on and there's still not a good way to do this.  This is why people start UWP projects and then toss them on the trash heap after 25 minutes and go use something that doesn't have 4,592 roadblocks.